# If I dodge, absorb, or block an attack, did I get hit?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

For some of the "Challenge" achievements, the specific challenge revolves around killing a boss without getting hit, or hit by specific attacks:

[image: Cropped screenshot of an achievement entry: Fist Missed: Kill Belial without getting hit by his fist attack.]

It occurs to me that loading up on dodge and/or block might save a boss run for this achievement if I get particularly lucky.  I'm not sure if this counts, though.  If the attack intersects my location, but I took no damage (ie, I dodged or blocked), does this count as getting hit?

How do abilities that absorb damage change things?  Can I keep something like [Diamond Skin](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/diamond-skin) on and "cheat" that way?

Comment: Good question. I'm also interested in [absorbing](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/diamond-skin) [damage](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/serenity), but its not worth another question.

Comment: @dpatchery, ooh, that's a good point.  I'll extend so that perhaps we can get a better/more complete answer.

Comment: and what about avoiding the damage with Smoke Screen? I know it's technically the same as Diamond Skin, but i don't know...

Comment: I can test the monk's ability later today.

Comment: @TimothyRoy diamond skin is not the same as smokescreen - smokescreen is an immunity, diamond skin is an absorb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of the achievements, not getting hit means not taking damage. Using abilities like Smokescreen (pure immunity) counts, Diamond skin (absorption) also counts, dodging counts. Block does not count. In the case of block you're only reducing the damage taken rather than avoiding it.

For example, on the Belial encounter I have got the 'bad breath' (avoid being hit by his flame breath) achievement on both a Wizard and a Demon Hunter through the use of their immunities - no moving, just saw the attack coming and popped a cooldown.

So yes - you can use immunity abilities to get these achievements, and a fluke dodge will count towards the achievement as well.

Comment: Expanding on this - it is possible to block 100% of the incoming damage and this will result in you 'not being hit' also. The only way this can happen though is when you're out gearing the content and the block value on your shield is higher than the incoming hit.

Comment: Just wondering how did you get *Bad Breath* achievement on **BOTH** Wizard and DH? AFAIK achievements are account-wide, so you can only earn it once

Comment: Achievements are not shared across accounts and because I had two active WoW accounts during the period that the "subscribe to WoW for one year and get Diablo 3 free" I ended up with multiple Diablo 3 accounts as well!

Comment: This seems to be the case. For example, I've achieved [Uncaged](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Uncaged) by Smoke Screening immediately after Diablo picked me up from the cage. It seems that not getting hit is the same as not taking damage.

Answer (score 2):

Dodging definitely does not count as getting hit, as I just got that achievement as a monk (with ~40% dodge chance) and saw 'Dodged' for many fist attacks.

**EDIT**: Ignore this, I missed the Inferno difficulty requirement in the achievement.

Comment: RE: your point on serenity, this is strange as I've gained the bad breath achievement simply by popping a cooldown (Smokescreen@DH, Diamond Skin@Wizard) and staying still with the breath passing me. From what you're saying I'd still expect Smokescreen to work (it is an immunity) but Diamond Skin is an absorption effect...

Comment: @ickleislands I was playing on Nightmare and missed that the achievement requires Inferno, edited to correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, a hit is when the monters hits and hurts you, if you move, block, dodge or something like that it doesn't counts.

Comment: Blocking an attack can still mean that the monster has hit and hurt you.

Answer (score 1):

I will have to do some tests, but I'm fairly sure that a "hit" counts when a monster hits you, regardless of the end result to your hp

So dodging will not count as a "hit", however blocking or absorbing the damage will

Comment: Even if you dodge an attack, it will still interrupt your town portal or resurrection.  I believe you are still "hit"